# How to create binding from Expression instead of string?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to create a Binding from a Expression rather than having to hardcode the name of the Property?

Normally you do:

```
new Binding("MyPropertyName")
```

Is there a way, part of the Framework, that you could do instead, something like:

```
new Binding(x=> x.MyPropertyName)
```

Does the Framework offer this feature?

Comment: I don't think the type inference system would be able to determine what type `x`  is in your example.  You would need something like `new Binding(MyThing x=> x.MyPropertyName)` for it to work at all.  I don't think this directly exists, but you could easily create a helper function to do it.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - Yes, I just wrote a lose example to get my point across,  I realize the x is not enough information, thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment is not possible. You have to wait for C# 6.0 and **nameof** operator - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx

In other way you can use this simply method:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}
```